# Automatically add numbers into rows of 10 - Google Script

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script

First post, not so much a problem more advice.

I have been working on a loop to add a certain amount of numbers into rows of 10 in Google Scripts. I have the below code working but can't help thinking that there is a simpler way of achieving this.

I have commented the code explaining what section does what, but essentially it takes a number from a different cell, then creates rows of consecutive numbers in groups of 10.

```
function orderArea1() {
  for(x = 0, y = 0, z = 1; z <= releaseNoteSH.getRange(10, 4).getValue(); z++){ // Sets variables; checks the z is lower or equal to source quantity, increase z by 1

  y = y + 0.099; // Add 0.099 to y. This is to stop the row reference changing too early

  releaseNoteSH.getRange(Math.floor(y + 10), x + 6).setValue(z); // Set location of first number using y rounded down to the nearest integer, and set value using z

  x++; // Add 1 to x

  if(x >= 10){ // If/when x reaches 10 reset x to 0
    x = 0;
  }
  }
}
```

If anyone can give me an idea on how to simplify this I'd be very interested to hear!

I have only been learning JavaScript for a week or so now and this website has been invaluable so thanks to everyone on here!

Comment: You didn't define releaseNoteSH.  Perhaps something like this `var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();var releaseNoteSH=ss.getSheetByName('releaseNote');` might be appropriate.

Comment: Apologies @Cooper this was defined earlier in the script, should have included that in the example! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

There's a lot to talk about here, but I have to say for a developer in their first week, this is a pretty clever hack.

It looks like you want to end up with something like this:

```
releaseNoteSH.getRange(row, col).setValue(z);
```

Where `z` is a number that starts at 1 and goes up to some unknown limit, `row` is a number 10 or higher, depending on how many rows there are, and `col` is a number between 6 and 15, depending on where we are in the row. The correct way to calculate a row and column from a single number looks like this:

```
var row = Math.floor(z/10); // This number starts at 0 and goes up by 1 every time z goes up by 10
var col = z % 10; // This number starts at 0 and goes up along with z, but starts over every time it hits 10
releaseNoteSH.getRange(row + 10, col + 6).setValue(z + 1); // Because z now starts at 0
```

For rows we divide by the size we want the rows to be, and round down. For everyone's sanity, we're going to start counting z at 0.

For  columns, you would read that line out loud as, "col equals z mod one." `%` is the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) in javascript (as long as you're using positive numbers). Modulo is a basic arithmetic operation that's very important in programming, but not taught in in schools alongside `+`, `-`, etc. for some reason. It means, "divide the left number by the right, and return the remainder instead of the answer. So for numbers 0-9, `z / 10` equals 0, with a remainder of `z`. Then for numbers 10-19, `z / 10` is 1, with a remainder of `z`, and so on.

Putting it all together:

```
var max = releaseNoteSH.getRange(10, 4).getValue();

for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  var row = Math.floor(i/10);
  var col = i % 10;
  releaseNoteSH.getRange(row + 10, col + 6).setValue(i + 1);
}
```

The other improvement this version makes is to store the number we're counting up to in a variable outside the loop. Currently, your code will call `releaseNoteSH.getRange(10, 4).getValue();` every single time the loop runs. Since the number in in that cell will always be the same, all those function calls are a waste of time.

Your next improvement is to figure out how to use the [app scripts API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) to only call `releaseNoteSH.getRange()` once instead of repeating it inside the loop every time.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks very much for the detailed explanation. I will get looking into only calling the getRange once I'm guessing that will speed up the function a bit because at the moment its running pretty slowly. I knew the original was a bit clunky and it took a lot of Logger.log tests to get the variables where I wanted them. Thanks again!